# Find a javascript object with a specific method in the global scope

Tags: javascript, object

I'm looking at a minified (and potentially obfuscated) javascript code. I'm trying to find object(s) that have a method defined on them with specific method signature. But these objects are nested and buried somewhere deep down and I don't even know their names. I have tried exploring the Global scope in the browser manually, but that seems humanly impossible.

Luckily, what I do know is that the objects of interest have a method called `sell`, for example, defined on them. How can I recursively traverse do/up all the objects in my browser console's global scope to figure out what these objects are?

Comment: Does this work? `Object.values( window ).filter(v => typeof v?.sell === 'function')`

Comment: @adiga sadly it only works at the global scope level and doesn't take into account nested objects (something I'd need in this case where the object of interested is nested very deep down).

Comment: I would use the Chrome debugger, put a breakpoint in somewhere close to where that method is called, take a look at the stack trace and/or step through the code line by line til you see it.  Pretty printing the obfuscated code in the chrome debugger can help make it less insane.

Comment: @James That's my only resort for now- the code is a sphagetti of anonymous functions and eval operations, using breakpoints is helping a bit, but it's difficult to trace which calle is orchestrating what, especially given the humongous numbers of variables in every scope.

Comment: What about loading the text contents of the page into a text editor and  searching for the text that best matches the function signature you want to find? I'm assuming that when you say signature, you're referring to the function's name, if there is one, and it's parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

First you need to make object-scan available in your browser console

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.6.9';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

And then you can execute a search

```js
objectScan(
  ['**'],
  {
    abort: true,
    rtn: 'parent',
    breakFn: ({ isCircular }) => isCircular,
    filterFn: ({ property, value }) => property === 'toString' && typeof value === 'function'
  }
)(window);
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of object-scan

Comment: [Please don't forget your disclaimer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) :-)

Comment: Dang, I use a script to generate and verify my answers. But this one I couldn't do... that's why I forgot...